# self.dismiss does nothing on 3rd level segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, dismiss

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller.  I segue to a view controller via a "show" segue.  From there I navigate to a tableviewcontroller  via a "show" segue.  The navigation bar shows up with the back button but upon didclickrow self.dismiss does nothing.  The completion block never executes. I'm baffled.  There has to be some rule I don't understand about view controllers.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    print( "THIS NEVER EXECUTES AND NOTHING HAPPENS" )
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "show segue" is used to push a view controller.
So your code will not work as you are trying to dismiss the view controller that was not presented.

You should dismiss only when a view controller is presented or you have used a "Present Modally Segue" type.

You should use `popViewController` when you have used "Push Segue" type or have pushed a view controller.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

While in a `UINavigationController`, You should use the function

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Or if you want to go back to the very top level view, use:

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller) for this function explains:

> This method removes the top view controller from the stack and makes the new top of the stack the active view controller. If the view controller at the top of the stack is the root view controller, this method does nothing.

Comment: does _ = mean the same thing as self?  It works like a charm.  In the words of Sheldon Cooper, "BAZINGA!"

Comment: _ is the name of a variable which doesn't get called. In this situation, you are right it works the same as self. By calling the "variable" _, the code gets ran and the variable doesn't need to be referenced in the future.